# How do I interpret the two "=" and the whole of this expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, debugging, neural-network

```
train_acc = np.mean(y_train == y_train_pred)
```

How does the assignment and evaluation of this expression work?

Answer (score 1):

Simple, let's assume you have these two numpy arrays:

```
y_train = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4])
y_train_pred = np.array([1, 2, 3, 5])
```

As we can see, these two arrays differ only in the last element. So, when we apply `y_train == y_train_pred`, we will get:

```
>>> y_train == y_train_pred
array([ True,  True,  True, False])
# same as array([ 1,  1,  1, 0])
```

Now, when we apply the `np.mean`, we will get the mean of it which will be `3/4`:

```
>>> np.mean(y_train == y_train_pred)
0.75
```

So, to answer your question: what does `==` means in the previous syntax? It simply means iterate over the numpy array and check if every element in `y_train` equals the opposing element of `y_train_pred` and return either `True` if they match and `False` if they don't.

Hope this answers your question!!

Answer (score 0):

`y_train == y_train_pred` is evaluated on an element-by-element basis and the result is a boolean array with the same number of elements as in `y_train` and `y_train_pred`. When two corresponding elements in both arrays are the same, the resulting element is True. Otherwise it's False. Then `np.mean()` calculates the number of the True elements and divides it by the length of the array. The result is assigned to `train_acc`.